# Does it make sense to say that signals are ordered? That e.g. for $a < b$, $a$ Hz < $b$ Hz?

Tags: oscillators

Does it make sense to say that signals are ordered? That e.g. for $a < b$, $a$ Hz < $b$ Hz?

While numerically it might seem reasonable, physically I don't understand what sense would it make to say that a lower musical note is "contained in" a higher musical note. Or does it? E.g. if one limits oneself to units of seconds? So that $a$ Hz contains fewer cycles than $b$ Hz, per second.

Comment: You can always _define_ the symbol "$<$" to mean whatever you want. For example, I could say "alligator $<$ crocodile" to mean that alligator comes first in the dictionary. But it doesn't mean that all alligators weigh less than all crocodiles. Whether $<$ makes sense depends entirely on what you decide it means.

Comment: @knzhoue Then where does the association of a higher frequency = higher perceived pitch come from? Like how have people decided what higher pitch and lower pitch refer to?

Comment: That is a historical, cultural, or biological question, not a math or physics question. Honestly, I've never heard a convincing explanation.